# Extract variables from text string Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides

I created a Google Slides that contains a lot of variables. I want to be able to pull all variables I have in there at once to Google Sheets. I'm using apps script to get all of the texts as strings from all shapes in the slides.

I have strings that includes both text and variables.

```
The text contains {{variable1}} and {{variable2}} and also some more {{variable3}}
```

The desired output is to get an array with all of the variables names.

```
[variable1, variable2, variable3]
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is best to add examples of what you have tried to get it work so that people may help you with your code.

Comment: probably should use regex to match for words surrounded by curly braces, and then, map over the array to remove the curly braces.

Comment: @beskgar I honestly didn't knew where to start from :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const input = "The text contains {{variable1}} and {{variable2}} and also some more {{variable3}}"
const regex = /{{(\w+)}}/g
const matches = [...input.matchAll(regex)]
console.log(matches.map(([, x]) => x))
```

Even if you don't know regexes you can make do with split(). It's quite hacky though

```js
const input = "The text contains {{variable1}} and {{variable2}} and also some more {{variable3}}"

console.log(input.split('{{').slice(1).map(x => x.split('}}')[0]))
```

Comment: Thank you, eventually I used the regex one.